# URL filter not working in Designer

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2007, sharepoint-designer

I'm using Sharepoint 2007. I have a page that uses a URL filter to display selected content from a list. When I display the page in the browser without supplying a parameter, the page displays an empty list, as expected. The parameter value is a string, and the default is "0", which isn't used in the list. The filter works perfectly in the browser.

However, when I edit the page in Designer, it instead displays *all* of the list content. Is there a way to enable the filter in Designer so that I don't have to look at all that content while trying to edit the web parts?